# Сравнение полученных от сервер значений в JS

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Здравствуйте! С помощью функции отправляю запрос на сервер:

```
function sync_query(url, data)
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', url, false);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send(data);

    if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200)
    {
        return xhr.responseText;
    }
}
```

На сервере возвращаю ответ: `echo json_encode('1');` 
Вызываю функцию и пытаюсь сравнить результат: `if(sync_query(url, data) == 1){...}else{...}`, но почему то сравнение происходит не корректно(

Comment: Попробуйте выводить не строку `'1'`, а число 1, вот так: `echo json_encode(1);`.

Comment: @Maxim Zasorin, все равно некорректно

Comment: а запрос выполняется корректно? Проверьте, что у вас возвращает функция `sync_query`.